# How to handle http error code 303 in volley

Tags: android, android-volley, httpresponse, jsonresponse

I tried to override deliverError method but still facing the problem.
My request is https but on error response location I am receiving an http url.
What is significance of location in error response?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this version of **volley** library here: https://github.com/samkirton/android-volley

Add to your gradle :

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

I hope this should resolve your issue

Comment: It is an old project in eclipse so I had downloaded the latest jar from 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.19
and put it in class path, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.
For sdk version greater than or equal to 9, volley internally use HttpURLConnection. As other related answers mentioned, HttpURLConnection will not redirect to a schema with different protocol. That means a 30x from https to http or vise versa is not automatically handled in volley. You are going to get an Error in deliverError if such a response is returned.

The version from https://github.com/samkirton/android-volley seems to have dealt with 301, 302, not all 30x. But I'm not sure.

By the way, 30x is generally treated as error in almost all libs that implements http. This should not be a problem. You may consider retrieving the url from location and making a request by your own